# Ratchet with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ratchet

I am planning to create an instant messaging service using Ratchet and laravel(I found a project called latchet, which integrates Ratchet into laravel)

My question is.

1. How to verify a client before allowing him to start a web socket connection.
2. One user can be part of multiple groups, so I want to create channels like Poll_grp_id , and get a list of all of a user's groups, and then subscribe to all those Poll_Grp_id channels. I am not sure about how to go about doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $userKey) {
    //check if the userKey is correct for that user, ...
}
```

I use this myself with an APIKey, and each time a user subscribes, they send the $userKey object with it.

That object contains only the userId, apiKey, ...(whatever you need to verify the user)

The second question:

//code from socketo.me to give an example

```
protected $subscribedTopics = array();

public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    $this->subscribedTopics[$topic->getId()] = $topic;
}

/**
 * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
 */
public function onBlogEntry($entry) {
    $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

    // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
    if (!array_key_exists($entryData['category'], $this->subscribedTopics)) {
        return;
    }

    $topic = $this->subscribedTopics[$entryData['category']];

    // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
    $topic->broadcast($entryData);
}
```

In this you would change the `onSubscribe($conn, $topic)` to `onSubscribe($conn, $topicArray)`

Afterwards you get all seperate 'channels' from that array and add them to the `$subscribedTopics`

When you try to send something to those 'channels'/'topics', It will then send it to all connected clients that had the particular channel in their `$topicArray`

I hope this helps.

Comment: say I do some action on another controller. How can I invoke a method from a class that implements a MessageComponentInterface to send a string to client ?

Comment: since you want to invoke it from other methods I would suggest you to check the pushserver part of the socketo.me tutorial. That alows you to push data from the servercode through the socket.

Comment: I just tried out your suggestion. Please take a look at my new question that I have posted .the message is not getting sent